# Show divergence of infinite series $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n(n+1)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am having trouble showing that this series is divergent. I do see that
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n(n+1)}} = \frac{1}{n\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}}}$.

However, I can't find a series that is smaller and diverges to infinity, as $n \leq n\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{n}}$.

I have tried the root test as well, but I am not sure wether the following is correct:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}((1+ \frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$.

Edit:

$\sqrt(n)\sqrt(n+1) = n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \leq n \sqrt{2} < 2n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thus follows
$0 \leq \frac{1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$.

$\frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{1}{n}  = \sum \frac{1}{2n}$ diverges, so by the comparison test $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n(n+1)}}$ also diverges.

Comment: You are right about the root test, it is inconclusive. To solve the problem, note that by your calculation the $n$-th term is $\ge \frac{1}{2n}$. Continue.

Comment: I have edited my post, is this correct?

Comment: Almost fine. You should really prove that $\sqrt{n(n+1)}\le 2n$. By what you had written, we have $\sqrt{n(n+1)}=n\sqrt{1+1/n}\le n\sqrt{2}\lt 2n$. Or else you could just use the $\sqrt{2}$, and conclude that your $n$-th term is $\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n}$, then the proof finishes in the same way as your.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \ge \frac 1 {\sqrt{(n+1)^2}} = \frac 1 {n+1} \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n+1} =\infty.
$$

**PS inspired by a comment below:**
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n+1} & = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 5 + \cdots \\[10pt]
& = \left( 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 5 \cdots \right) - 1 \\[10pt]
& = \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n \right) - 1.
\end{align}
If you change only finitely many terms of a sequence (in this case by deleting only one term), you don't alter whether the series converges or not, nor whether the divergence is to $\infty$.

Comment: But I can't simply use that  $\sum \frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges, unless I show that as well. I can only assume that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent

Comment: @user260710 : The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n+1}$ is merely the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ with the first term deleted. $\qquad$

Comment: @user260710 : I've added a postscript to the answer to clarify this. $\qquad$